# Automatic styling for definition lists between two alernatives

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve the following. When all the items in a definition list are short, such as up to three characters or so, I would like something like the grid styling:

```
x  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

y  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

But if the items are longer, then to overhang:

```
x longer item
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

y longer item
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

In a mixture, it is not specified whether the short items have a line break; i could be:

```
x longer item
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

y  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

or

```
y
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

If I set a width on the column in the grid style (by any means, whether with `grid-auto-columns` with a maximum width, or a hard `width`) , then the items are simply word-wrapped to fit the column, and in the case of long words, the text overlaps with the definition.

Can this be done with nothing but CSS, without rewriting the HTML?

The `<dl>` elements all have a `class="items"` attribute, so can be targeted with `dl.items`, but otherwise no indication of whether they are long or short items.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
      dl.items { /* ??? */ }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <dl class="items">
       <dt>x</dt>
       <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
           magna aliqua.</dd>


       <dt>y</dt>
       <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
           nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="items">
       <dt>longer item x</dt>
       <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
           magna aliqua.</dd>


       <dt>longer item y</dt>
       <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
           nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
    </dl>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: But styling based on text length is a job for JS.

Comment: *Can this be done with nothing but CSS, without rewriting the HTML?* --> we need to see the html then

Comment: Ideally whatever outputs the html can add an extra class if the item is long/short then you can control everything with ease with css

Comment: @Huangism Indeed, if the elements are distinguished by class, you can give them completely separate, unrelated styling. For that, I would not have to ask how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float can approximate this:

```css
dl dd {
  overflow: auto;
  /* adjust the 40px to the value you want */
  min-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin-left:40px;
}

dl dt {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<dl class="items">
    <dt>x</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</dd>


    <dt>y</dt>
    <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
    
    <dt>zzzz</dt>
    <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
    
    <dt>zzzz zzzz</dt>
    <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="items">
    <dt>longer item x</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</dd>


    <dt>longer item y</dt>
    <dd>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: That looks great! I experimented with `float` (because I have worked with it in other contexts where it achieved a similar behavior), but not in the right way. Instead of 40px, I tried it with a font-relative 4em, and I added a `margin-bottom: 1ex` to the `dd` separate the items.

Comment: When some `<dd>` items are empty (which I have in a few rare cases), the float misbehaves. But, that's an easy fix: with CSS we can target empty elements with `:empty` and use `content: "\00A0"` to put something in them.

Comment: @Kaz or add `clear:left` to `dt`, it should also do it